# natural logarithm of a complex number $\ln(a+bi)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to find a formula for $\ln(a+bi)$, is my working correct?

$$a+bi=re^{i\theta},\,\,r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\,\,\theta=\frac{|b|}{b}\arctan\left(\frac ba\right)$$
and so:
$$\ln(a+bi)=\ln(re^{i\theta})=\frac{\ln(r^2)}{2}+i\theta$$
$$\therefore \ln(a+bi)=\frac{\ln(a^2+b^2)}{2}+i\frac{|b|}{b}\arctan\left(\frac ba\right)$$

---

I would also like to calculate: $$(a+bi)^{c+di}$$ and using a similar method I got:
$$(a+bi)^{c+di}=(a^2+b^2)^{c/2}\exp\left(-\frac{d|b|}{b}\arctan\left[\frac ba\right]\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{c|b|}{b}\arctan\left[\frac ba\right]\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{c|b|}{b}\arctan\left[\frac ba\right]\right)\right]\left[\cos\left(\frac d2\ln(a^2+b^2)\right)+i\sin\left(\frac d2\ln(a^2+b^2)\right)\right]$$
could anyone confirm if this is correct? Thanks

Comment: Your formula for $\theta$ is correct only if $a,b>0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part You also have to specify which branch of the logarithm is considered.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ assumed to be real numbers?

Comment: Yeah a and b are real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have $z^u$ it is convenient to have $z=a+ib=re^{i\theta}$ in polar form and keep $u=c+id$ in cartesian form.

The polar formula is $\begin{cases}r=|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\\theta=\operatorname{atan2}(b,a)\end{cases}$

You got it ok, but for the angle it is more convenient to use **atan2** which deals with the proper quadrants for the angle (this function is defined on most systems that have a math library):

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

We have $\ln(z)=\ln(r)+i\theta+2ik\pi\quad k\in\mathbb Z$, and it is important to keep this $k$ because the complex logarithm is multivalued (i.e. it has branches).

It ensures that formulas like $z^{u}\times z^v=z^{u+v}$ and $(z^u)^v=z^{uv}\ $  stays true at least for some value of $k$.

$\begin{align}z^u
&=\exp\bigg(u\ln(z)\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg((c+id)(\ln(r)+i\theta)+2ik\pi)\bigg)\\
&=\exp\bigg((c\ln(r)-d\theta)+i(c\theta+d\ln(r)+(-2kd\pi+2ikc\pi)\bigg)
\end{align}$

So we have the formula $\boxed{z^u\in\bigg\{z_{[k]}=z_{[0]}\ w^k\mid k\in\mathbb Z\bigg\}}$ where:
$$\begin{cases}z_{[0]}&=r^c\ e^{-d\theta}\ \bigg(\cos\big(c\theta+d\ln(r)\big)+i\sin\big(c\theta+d\ln(r)\big)\bigg)\\\\w&=e^{-2d\pi}\ \bigg(\cos(2c\pi)+i\sin(2c\pi)\bigg)\end{cases}$$

Comparatively to your formula (i.e. $z_{[0]}$), you still have a complex multiplication remaining, while I separated real part and imaginary part, but this is basically the same.

But I also have the multiplicative factor $w^k$ which correspond the the branches of the complex log.

The value $z_{[0]}$ obtained for $k=0$ is called the principal value.

*Note: the principal value is not necessarily the "simplest" one, it happens that some other $z_{[k]}$ is simpler (i.e. real for instance) for a value of $k\neq 0$*.