# Find the principal value of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been given the number
\begin{equation}
i^{2-3i}
\end{equation}
I've used the following formula
\begin{equation}
z^c=e^{(c\log{z})}
\end{equation}
Which has given me
\begin{equation}
e^{(2-3i)\log{i}}
\end{equation}
I'm unsure if this is the principal value? Or on what I have to do next

Comment: Use what you know about the $ \log $ function to compute (the principle value of) $ \log i $.

Comment: It is a multi valued answer, but I would assume using the principal would be sufficient to show your knowledge

Comment: use De Moivre's theorem

Answer (score 2):

$$i^{2-3i}=e^{(2-3i)\text{Log}\,i}=e^{(2-3i)\left(\log|i|+i\arg i\right)}=e^{(2-3i)\cdot\pi i/2}=e^{\pi i+\frac32\pi}=-e^{\frac{3\pi}2}$$

The principal value of a complex number is usually accepted as having argument in $\;[0,2\pi)\;$

Comment: Do you use (like me) $\text{Log}$ as $\log_{10}$ :-)?

Comment: @Sebastiano No. it is used in higer mathematics to denote by $\;\log x\;$ the natural logarithm, what you  probably denote by $\;\ln x\;$. In this case though Log$\,x\;$ is the *complex* logarithm (the usual branch of it), whereas $\;\log\;$ is the natural *real* logarithm

Comment: In old math books, the capital letter L is used to indicate base 10. I use $\log$ like $\ln$.

Answer (score 1):

For a more general overview https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3729281/399263

Note that when we have $z^u$ we are interested in $\ln(z)$ principal value because we have to choose a branch of the logarithm, the exponent $u$ does not pose an issue.

In fact setting $\begin{cases} z=a+ib=re^{i\theta}\\u=c+id\end{cases}$

If we consider $\arg(z^u)=\big(d\ln(r)+c(\theta+2k\pi)\big)\bigg|_{k\in\mathbb Z}$ it may not have values inside $[0,2\pi)$ (if $c$ is large) or have many (if $c$ is small), you could eventually choose a $k_0$ that minimize the absolute value of the argument but would that be really relevant ?

It makes more sense to take $k=0$ which correspond to the principal value of $\ln(z)$, which is the operation that leads to multivaluation.

In our case $z=i$ and $u=2-3i$

So $\ i^{2-3i}=\exp((2-3i)(i\frac{\pi}2+2ik\pi))=\exp(\frac{3\pi}2+i\pi+6k\pi+4ik\pi)=z_0\times w^k$

Since $\exp(i\pi)=-1$ and $\exp(4ik\pi)=1$ we have
$$i^{2-3i} = z_0\times w^k\quad\text{where } \begin{cases}z_0=-e^{\frac{3\pi}2}\\ w=e^{6\pi}\end{cases}\ \text{ and }\ k\in\mathbb Z$$

And this is this $z_0$ we call the principal value.