# What is the value of $\ln(e^{2i\pi})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

According to Euler's formula, $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta;$ so, $e^{2\pi i} = 1.$ And $\ln(1) = 0.$

On the other hand, $\ln(e^{i\theta}) = i\theta,$ so $\ln(e^{2\pi i}) = 2\pi i$.

Is $\ln(e^{2i\pi})$ equal to $0$ or $2\pi i$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Good first question.

Comment: What do you mean by $\ln z$ for a complex number $z$?

Comment: $2\pi i+2n\pi i$ is **a logarithm** of $e^{2\pi i}$ for every integer $n$.

Comment: Congratulations! You've discovered that complex logarithm is multi-valued.

Comment: Very good question, you should study about Complex Logarithms. And you will be able to answer your question yourself. Happy learning!

Comment: Thanks! I just understood the $e^{i\theta}$ is $2 \pi$ periodic!

Comment: You can view $\ln$ as a (holomorphic) function on the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left\{ 0\right\}$. Then $e^{2\pi i}$ is a unique point of that space for which $\ln(e^{2\pi i})=2\pi i$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#The_associated_Riemann_surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural logarithm is multivalued with respect to complex numbers. This means that the natural logarithm is not a function because its outputs are not unique. In order to deal with this, mathematicians tend to view what they call the "principal branch" of the natural logarithm or the main branch, denoted "$\operatorname{Ln} x$". While $\ln x$ is not a function, $\operatorname{Ln} x$ is. Therefore $\ln 1 = 0, 2\pi i,\dots$. In fact, it is equal to $2\pi in$ where $n$ is an integer all at the same time. It's not just 1 that has this property; all complex values for which the natural logarithm is defined share this property. However, given how it is generally defined, $\operatorname{Ln} x = 0$ only. If you know about $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$, it's kind of like that.

Great question. Let me know if I wasn't clear or if I got something wrong.

Also, as a side note, when using the $ for the math editing tool, you can write "\ln" in order to make it straight.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the way is to do the logarithm is to see the $\ln x$ as a whole but not directly evaluate $x$ then $\ln x$

Comment: No problem. It was a great question. I'm sorry, but I don't seem to understand what you are asking now.

Comment: @juzmathnerd To compute $\ln(e^{2i\pi})$ (there will be infinitely many values), use [definition (45) here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/clog_11.pdf). For example, the second equals sign in [this Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4290262/21813) is an application of this definition to compute $\ln(i).$

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the fact that
\begin{equation}
\log z = \log |z|+j (arg(z)+2n \pi)
\end{equation}
where $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2, ...$, and $j=\sqrt{-1}$. As you wrote $|e^{2 \pi j}|=1$, while $arg(e^{2 \pi j})=0$. The complex argument can be computed by using the arc tangent function of the ratio between imaginary part and real part of the complex number. When doing so we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
\log e^{2 \pi j} = 2n \pi j
\end{equation}
When n = 0  we refer to as the principal branch of the
logarithm; the corresponding value of the function is referred to as the principal value. If z is a real and positive number, we usually take $n = 0$ so that the principal branch of the complex logarithm function agrees with the usual one for real variables. In reality
the function $\log z$ is infinitely branched.